# `For loop` stays in 0

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm having a loop problem. It doesn't increase the 'i' value from 0. Can you help me?

Here's my code:

```
var users = ["a", "b", "c"];

if (users.length > 0) {
    $(".ajax").live("submit", function(){
        for (var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);

            var forma = $(this);

            $("input[name=_session]", forma).val(users[i]);

            ajaxy(forma, function(data){
                console.log(data.status);
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
} else...
```

Comment: What's the actual value of `users.length`? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Code is not well indented; clear code is a lot easier to read (the return false seems to be outside the for, when it is inside).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You return false after the first iteration of the loop. I think you need to move the `return false;` line out of the loop block.

Properly indenting your code will make errors like this obvious:

```
if (users.length > 0) {
    $(".ajax").live("submit", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            var forma = $(this);
            $("input[name=_session]", forma).val(users[i]);
            ajaxy(forma, function (data) {
                console.log(data.status);
            });
            return false; // This should not be here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: dammit I just thought of this right as you posted it :P, nice job.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't figured that the "return false" was in the loop.

Comment: Nice demonstration of the power of properly formatted code :)

Answer (score 3):

The return statement in the for loop is causing it to exit before it can get to the next iteration.

Comment: Sorry but @sachleen answered before ;)

Answer (score 2):

Because you return on the first iteration of the loop, methinks.